# horizontal menu breaks with dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, alignment

I have a horizontal social media menu that when hovered over has two options.
The menu is perfectly aligned outside of the hover state, but when an item is hovered over, the horizontal alignment breaks. I'm wondering how I can make it so that the drop down items display below the parent items without breaking the horizontal alignment?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhZmm/)

html/php-

```
<div class="social">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/instagram.png" alt="instagram" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">cait</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">shannon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/youtube.png" alt="youtube" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">cait</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">shannon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">cait</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">shannon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">cait</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">shannon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/pinterest.png" alt="lockerz" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">cait</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">shannon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end social -->
```

css-

```
#header .social {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#header .social ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#header .social ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#header .social ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

#header .social ul li a {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#header .social ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#header .social ul li:hover li {
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things need to be fixed:

(1) You are giving your LI `display:inline` initially and then `display: block` on hover, which is why your horizontal alignment is breaking. Get rid of the hover state for the LI and set its display to `inline-block`.

(2) You give you embedded UL `position:relative`, so when it displays it's still in the page's flow and increases the width of the parent LI.  Give it `position:absolute` instead (and set its padding to 0).

Your CSS should look like this:

```
#header .social {
float: right;
list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#header .social ul {
    position: relative;
}

#header .social ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#header .social ul li ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#header .social ul li a {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#header .social ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VAqWD/1/)

Comment: Removing `display: block` either disabled the hover effect entirely, or made no changes in how the menu operated depending on which elements it was removed from.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation.